# MapReduce Partitioner program producing empty output

Tags: hadoop-partitioning, ubuntu-23.10

Hadoop version: 3.3.6
Virtual Machine: UTM
Virtual Machine OS: Ubuntu 23.10
My machine OS: macOS

Below is the source code of the program.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package partition;
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class partition 
{
   //Map class
    
   public static class MapClass extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>
   {
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      {
         try{
            String[] str = value.toString().split("\t", -3);
            String gender=str[3];
            //key = gender, value = whole string
            context.write(new Text(gender), new Text(value));
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }
   
   //Reducer class
    
   public static class ReduceClass extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,IntWritable>
   {
      public int max = -1;
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable <Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
      {
          //find maximum
         max = -1;
            
         for (Text val : values)
         {
            String [] str = val.toString().split("\t", -3);
            if(Integer.parseInt(str[4])>max)
            max=Integer.parseInt(str[4]);
         }
            
         context.write(new Text(key), new IntWritable(max));
      }
   }
   
   //Partitioner class
    
   public static class CaderPartitioner extends
   Partitioner < Text, Text >
   {
      @Override
      public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks)
      {
          //partitions
         String[] str = value.toString().split("\t");
         int age = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
         
         if(numReduceTasks == 0)
         {
            return 0;
         }
         
         if(age<=20)
         {
            return 0;
         }
         else if(age>20 && age<=30)
         {
            return 1 % numReduceTasks;
         }
         else
         {
            return 2 % numReduceTasks;
         }
      }
   }
   

   public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception
   {
      Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        
      Job job = new Job(conf, "topsal");
      job.setJarByClass(partition.class); /*Change name*/
        
      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(arg[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(arg[1]));
        
      job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
        
      job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
      
      //set partitioner statement
        
      job.setPartitionerClass(CaderPartitioner.class);
      job.setReducerClass(ReduceClass.class);
      job.setNumReduceTasks(3);
      job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        
      job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        
      System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0 : 1);
      
      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

This is last part of the console output. Showing only this due to characters constraint.

```
2024-01-11 11:46:00,566 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(353)) - Finishing task: attempt_local584038357_0001_r_000002_0
2024-01-11 11:46:00,566 INFO  [Thread-23] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(486)) - reduce task executor complete.
2024-01-11 11:46:01,224 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1748)) - Job job_local584038357_0001 running in uber mode : false
2024-01-11 11:46:01,225 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1755)) -  map 100% reduce 100%
2024-01-11 11:46:01,226 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1766)) - Job job_local584038357_0001 completed successfully
2024-01-11 11:46:01,231 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1773)) - Counters: 30
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=3588
        FILE: Number of bytes written=2460844
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=14
        Map output records=0
        Map output bytes=0
        Map output materialized bytes=18
        Input split bytes=145
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=0
        Reduce shuffle bytes=18
        Reduce input records=0
        Reduce output records=0
        Spilled Records=0
        Shuffled Maps =3
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=3
        GC time elapsed (ms)=8
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=866123776
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=546
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=24
```

I am generating the output by configuring the arguments from the properties. However, when I check the output file, it is empty.
[Arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3mX2.png)

[Empty Output files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfeKY.png)

[Empty Output for example, part-r-00000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LIF7.png)

May I please ask what is the issue here? Is there something I need to update in the source code?